# tying two separate std::lists to each other

Tags: c++, std, stdlist

OK, it's a weird problem, I'm not sure there's a solution for that.

I have two lists, say a list of clients and list of some data per each client. I'm interested to keep the two lists in two separate `std::list`s because I have an API for providing the clients-list but I don't want to provide the rest of the data along with it.

However, as both lists should be aligned against each other, i.e. element n in each list should refer to the same client, I'm seeking for a way to link between them such that an element of one list won't be able to be added/removed without adding/removing the corresponding element in the other list, but still keep them in two separate lists for the API purpose that I mentioned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the API need to return `const std::list<Client>&`?  Or can it return something else that has `begin()` and `end()` iterators?

Comment: [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) is the way to go here

Comment: @aschepler, anything that has `begin()` and `end()` iterators is fine, but without any need of copying or other actions when it's requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a really simple encapsulation

```
class TwoLists{
  ...
  void addNode(clientstuff a, datastuff b);
  void removeNode(int index);
  const std::list<clientstuff>& GetClientList();
private:
  std::list<clientstuff> clientList; 
  std::list<datastuff> datalist;
}

void TwoLists::addNode(clientstuff a, datastuff b);
{
  //add a to clientList, and add b to dataList
}

void TwoLists::removeNode(int n)
{
  //remove node n from both lists
}

const std::list<clientstuff>& TwoLists::GetClientList()
{
  return clientList;
}
```

Comment: It would be much better if `GetClientList` would return `const std::list<clientstuff>&`. There would be no copying and client code would monitor the 'live' list, not the stale copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you get to design the interface, I would go ahead and put them in a single container, but provide users with custom iterators that only allow access to the public client part.  `boost::iterator_adaptor` makes writing this sort of iterator easy.

```
#include "Client.hpp"
#include <list>
#include <boost/iterator_adaptor.hpp>

class ClientList {
public:
    class iterator;
    class const_iterator;
    iterator begin();
    const_iterator begin() const;
    iterator end();
    const_iterator end() const;

private:
    struct InternalData {
        //...
    };
    struct ClientAndData {
        Client client;
        InternalData data;
    };
    typedef std::list<ClientAndData> internal_list_type;
    internal_list_type m_clients;
    friend class iterator;
    friend class const_iterator;
};

class ClientList::iterator
    : public boost::iterator_adaptor<
        ClientList::iterator,                     // Derived type for CRTP
        ClientList::internal_list_type::iterator  // Iter type to encapsulate 
        Client >                                  // Data type to expose
{
private:
    explicit iterator(const base_type& base_iter)
      : iterator_adaptor(base_iter) {}
    Client& dereference() const { return base()->client; }
    friend class ClientList;
    // Allow boost to call dereference():
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
};

class ClientList::const_iterator
    : public boost::iterator_adaptor<
        ClientList::const_iterator,
        ClientList::internal_list_type::const_iterator
        const Client >
{
public:
    const_iterator(const iterator& iter)
      : iterator_adaptor(iter.base()) {}
private:
    explicit const_iterator(const base_type& base_iter)
      : iterator_adaptor(base_iter) {}
    const Client& dereference() const { return base()->client; }
    friend class ClientList;
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
};

inline ClientList::iterator ClientList::begin()
{ return iterator(m_clients.begin()); }

inline ClientList::const_iterator ClientList::begin() const
{ return const_iterator(m_clients.begin()); }

inline ClientList::iterator ClientList::end()
{ return iterator(m_clients.end()); }

inline ClientList::const_iterator ClientList::end() const
{ return const_iterator(m_clients.end()); }
```

Or if users of your code should only get `const Client&` references, you would only need one iterator type, which would look mostly like the `const_iterator` class above.

There is no copying of `Client` objects going on here; the users get references to the same objects that are within the private list.

This does expose a public `base()` member function in the iterator types, which could be used by somebody nasty to get at the `InternalData`.  But anyone who knows about or discovers `base()` should also know or come to realize that they're not supposed to use it.  If this worries you though, you could maybe inherit `iterator_adaptor` privately and then manually make all its public members *except* `base()` public again.  Or (probably easier), make everything in `InternalData` private or protected and then `friend` the classes on your side which will use it.